# Update wxpython figure canvas with new figure

Tags: python, matplotlib, wxpython

In a wxPython application I have an embedded a FigureCanvas with a matplotlib figure. I want to be able to switch the figure by loading a new one. However, the figure is not being updated.

Answers to similar topics suggests that `panel.canvas.draw()` and `panel.Refresh()` should do the trick, but I've also tried `panel.Update()` and `panel.canvas.Refresh()`. I fear that this only works if you want to redraw the canvas *with the same* figure?

So my question is: how do you replace the figure inside a canvas and make it update?

Below is a small (non-working) example. First a figure is loaded with a single axis. If you from the embedded shell type `panel.LoadFigure()` a new figure with 2x2 subplots is created and put into the canvas. But the new figure is not shown.

```
import numpy as np
import wx
from wx.py.shell import Shell

from matplotlib.backends.backend_wxagg import FigureCanvasWxAgg as FigureCanvas
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


class ShellPanel(wx.Panel):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent)
        self.shell = Shell(self)
        self.sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        self.sizer.Add(self.shell, 1, wx.GROW)
        self.SetSizer(self.sizer)
        self.Layout()
        self.Fit()


class FigurePanel(wx.Panel):
    def __init__(self, parent):

        wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent)
        self.parent = parent
        self.sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        self.figure, ax = plt.subplots()
        self.canvas = FigureCanvas(self, -1, self.figure)
        self.shellpanel = ShellPanel(self)
        s1 = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        s1.Add(self.canvas, 0, wx.GROW)
        s1.Add(self.shellpanel, 1 , wx.EXPAND)
        self.sizer.Add(s1, 5, wx.GROW)

        self.SetSizer(self.sizer)
        self.Layout()
        self.Fit()

    def LoadFigure(self):
        self.figure, ax = plt.subplots(2, 2)
        self.canvas.draw()
        self.Refresh()


class FigureFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, id, title, size):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent, id, title, size=size)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = wx.App(False)
    fr = FigureFrame(None, -1, title='Figure Loader', size=(wx.DisplaySize()[0]/2, wx.DisplaySize()[1]*3/4))
    panel = FigurePanel(fr)
    fr.Show()
    app.MainLoop()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is there any reason you are trying to create a new `Figure` and not simply new `Axes` on the already defined `Figure`?

I would write your code like so:

```
def LoadFigure(self):
    self.figure.clf()  # clear current figure
    # add arbitrary number of new Axes
    self.figure.add_subplot(221)
    self.figure.add_subplot(222)
    self.figure.add_subplot(223)
    self.figure.add_subplot(224)
    self.canvas.draw()  # refresh canvas
```

EDIT: following your comment, I think the problem is that you're creating a new figure, but your `Canvas` is still referencing the old one. I don't know if you can change that directly in the `FigureCanvas` properties, maybe someone with more experience can provide a better answer. For the moment, I would `Destroy` the previous canvas, and create a new `FigureCanvas` object with your new figure.

```
def LoadFigure(self):
    self.figure, ax = plt.subplots(2, 2)
    self.canvas.Destroy()
    self.canvas = FigureCanvas(self, -1, self.figure)
    self.canvas.draw()
```

Comment: The reason is that Im loading pickled figures from file. I.e. `fig = pickle.load(filename)`. This gives a new figure every time. So what I want to do is to update the canvas with this newer figure. The example code I wrote is somewhat stupid, as you showed with your example.

Comment: @pathoren OK, I understand now. I modified my answer to provide you with something that I believe works, but it's not pretty, there is probably a better way

Comment: Thank you @Diziet. I have had a similar solution as a backup plan but was hoping that there was a cleaner way of doing it.I wait a while to accept your answer to see if there's any other suggestions.

Comment: Inspired by your comment that the canvas is linked to the old figure, I figured out that you can use `self.canvas.figure = new_figure` to make sure the canvas is updated with the correct figure. This seems to work as far as I can see.

Comment: Noone else seems to give an answer so I accept your as the working one (together with my previous comment)!

Answer (score 0):

Try using the Figure itself to make your figure, not pyplot. It has usually worked for me because it gives you more room to improvise.

```
#!/usr/bin/python

# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import numpy as np
import wx
from wx.py.shell import Shell
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
from matplotlib.backends.backend_wxagg import FigureCanvasWxAgg as FigureCanvas
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


class ShellPanel(wx.Panel):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent)
        self.shell = Shell(self)
        self.sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        self.sizer.Add(self.shell, 1, wx.GROW)
        self.SetSizer(self.sizer)
        self.Layout()
        self.Fit()


class FigurePanel(wx.Panel):
    def __init__(self, parent):

        wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent)
        self.parent = parent
        self.sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        self.figure = Figure(figsize = (8,6.1), dpi =60)
        self.ax = self.figure.add_subplot(1,1,1)
        self.enlarged_figure = Figure(figsize = (8,6.1), dpi = 100)
        self.ax2 = self.enlarged_figure.add_subplot(2,1,2)
        self.canvas = FigureCanvas(self, -1, self.figure)
        self.canvas.Show()
        self.enlarged_canvas = FigureCanvas(self,-1,self.enlarged_figure)
        self.enlarged_canvas.Show()

        self.shellpanel = ShellPanel(self)
        s1 = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        s1.Add(self.canvas, 0, wx.GROW)
        s1.Add(self.shellpanel, 1 , wx.EXPAND)
        self.sizer.Add(s1, 5, wx.GROW)
        self.SetSizer(self.sizer)
        self.Layout()
        self.Fit()

    def LoadFigure(self):
        self.figure, ax = plt.subplots(2, 2)
        self.canvas.draw()
        self.Refresh()


class FigureFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, id, title, size):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent, id, title, size=size)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = wx.App(False)
    fr = FigureFrame(None, -1, title='Figure Loader', size=(wx.DisplaySize()[0]/2, wx.DisplaySize()[1]*3/4))
    panel = FigurePanel(fr)
    fr.Show()
    app.MainLoop()
```

In the shell type in 'panel.LoadFigure()' and the new figure will show up very quickly and then disappear. Then type 'panel.canvas.draw()' and the new figure will be there. Then type 'panel.LoadFigure()' to load the old figure back. Repeat.

I don't know why the figure remains hidden after the MainLoop() continues but this is sort of a quick fix to your problem.

Comment: After looking into this a bit, I think that the figures cannot stay on display when they are created by children of the main frame. For example, if you were to make a new class called 'myFrame' and then put the FigurePanel and ShellPanel as you have them there it will actually not even show the shell panel since it is created inside the FigurePanel class. However, if you create it in the main parent 'myFrame' then it will stay on display.